# Mapbox GL Geocoder - icon covers text and placeholder

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Mapbox GL geocoder's icon covers text and placeholder, is there a way to fix it or remove icon?
[image]
[image]

```
 var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
            mapboxgl: mapboxgl               
        });

        document.getElementById('geocoder').appendChild(geocoder.onAdd(map));
```

Geocoder DIV:

```
<div style="margin-left: -25px; margin-top: 10px;" id="geocoder" class="geocoder"></div>
```

Geocoder style:

```
 .geocoder {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
        width: 100%;            
    }
```

[Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9kdgjnq4/)

UPD: I think I found what is causing an issue, I have both geocoder.css and direction.css on same page.

Comment: Possible conflict with other CSS in the page? Can you set up a minimal reproducible case in JSFiddle or CodePen?

Comment: Have you definitely included the mapbox-gl-geocoder.css?

Comment: @SteveBennett yes I did.

Comment: @RafaelAlmeida added JSFiddle example.